# How can I make it so that my user input only accepts specific symbols?

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple calculator app and I've been racking my head on this one because I'm trying to loop the question whenever the user inputs the wrong choices.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nChoose an operation:");
Console.WriteLine("     ------------------  ");
Console.WriteLine("    | Addition:       + |");
Console.WriteLine("    | Subtraction:    - |");
Console.WriteLine("    | Multiplication: x |");
Console.WriteLine("    | Division:       / |");
Console.WriteLine("     ------------------  \n");

operators = Console.ReadLine();

while (operators != "+" || operators != "+" || operators != "+" || operators != "+")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input correct operation: ");
    operators = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would perhaps be simpler to understand if you replace your logic:

```
operator = Console.ReadLine();

var acceptableOperators = "+ - x /".Split();
while (!acceptableOperators.Contains(operator))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please input one of: " + string.Join(" or ", acceptableOperators);
  operator = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The crucial part is the logic becomes

"While not this list of acceptable operators contains the user input" or in other words, "while what the user inputted is not present in the list of acceptable operators"

This is easy to extend just by adding more operators to the string and the error message changes automatically. It supports multi char operators too

Note you shouldn't use a variable named as a plural if it isn't a collection or array (call your variable `operator`)

---

Your original logic was wrong for two reasons:

- One that you made a copy paste error that repeated `"+"` four times
- Two when humans say "check that this light is not blue or red" they mean `!(light == blue || light == red)` - the brackets are important. You could also say "check this light is not blue and is not red" to mean the same thing - in C# it's `light != blue && light != red`, but you cannot say "light is not blue OR light is not red" because it's always true no matter what color the light is.

Because (English speaking at least) humans tend to say the first form ("check the light isn't blue or red") without any obvious bracketing in the speech, it tends to guide newbies psychologically towards wanting to write  `light != blue || red` then they remember that c# has to repeat the variable for each check so it becomes  `light != blue || light != red` when it should have been `!(light == blue || light == red)`

Comment: Dude you're a life saver. Thanks! I'm kinda new to programming and everything is messed up. I forgot edit the "+" cause I was in a rush, I really appreciate you for pointing it out.

Comment: As an aside, if you're making a calculator, it might be good to make a method that asks the user for a number and just repeats the question if they don't enter a number - you'll be asking a user for more than one number so it makes sense not to repeat yourself. If this is a programming 101 class and they haven't taught what methods are yet make sure whoever teaches you to do it makes a good job of explaining so you don't get caught looking like you just copied something off the net without understanding it

Answer (score 1):

it should be && instead of ||, so user can only input + or - or x or /

```
while (operators != "+" && operators != "-" && operators != "x" && operators != "/")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input correct operation: ");
    operators = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic can be simplified and made more user friendly (not need to ask for an 'Enter' every time an operator is chosen):

```
        char key;
        while (true)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
            if ("+-x/".Contains(key)) break;
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease input correct operation: ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"You pressed {key}");
```